# Nuisance variable and rg.limit in R emmeans

Tags: r, regression, emmeans

I use R and I work with a quasibinomial model:

```r
mymodel=glm(dependent ~ explanatory1 + explanatory2 +
    explanatory3 + explanatory4 + explanatory5,
    family=quasibinomial, data=mydata)
```

`Anova(mymodel)` shows that `explanatory1` significantly affects `dependent`. So I used `emmeans` to do post-hoc paired comparisons:

```r
emmeans(mymodel, specs = pairwise ~ explanatory1)$contrasts
```

I got an error message

> The rows of your requested reference grid would be 19860, which exceeds the limit of 10000

So I did two different things :

```
emmeans(mymodel, specs = pairwise ~ explanatory1,
          rg.limit=20000)$contrasts

emmeans(mymodel, specs = pairwise ~ explanatory1, 
          nuisance="explanatory5")$contrasts
```

However, using these two different approaches, **I got exactly the same values** (for the estimate, SE, df, z.ratio, p.value). **Does anybody know why?**

Thanks for any comments.

I tried different models with or without interactions between explanatory variables and still got the same value with the "nuisance" and "rg.limit" approaches.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** If increasing `rg.limit` works, I don't see any reason you can't just use that approach and forget about `nuisance`. (The example in the vignette is one where using `rg.limit` would take >150Gb of memory, so often not practical ...)

But it makes sense/is good practice to try to understand what other approaches are doing and why they give identical answers in this case. Russ Lenth will probably be along soon to offer a definitive answer, but:

[The vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/messy-data.html#nuisance) gives a clear description of what the `nuisance` argument does:

> The reference grid is then constructed with those factors already averaged-out.

When would averaging out the effects of `nuisance` before constructing the reference grid give the same answer as including them (which is done with `rg.limit`)? It's hard to know exactly without seeing your data, but my guess is that you have a *balanced design*, so that (for example) the contribution of `beta_5*x5` to the prediction is the same as the contribution of `beta_5*mean(x5)`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. By "balanced design", do you mean having the same number of observations for all possible combinations of factor levels? If so, this is not the case in my data.  For example, `explanatory1` is education and there are not the same number of participants depending on the level of this factor.

Comment: OK. But to be honest I'm not sure exactly when there will be a difference between averaging before vs. averaging as part of the reference grid ...